# How to identify if text input was from hardware barcode scanner vs soft keyboard on android?

Tags: android, xamarin, barcode, android-softkeyboard

We have an app we are working on that is running on android devices with build in barcode scanners.  We're trying to identify whether the text input came from the soft keyboard or the barcode scanner because we want to give to make the input text box behave differently.

For example, if we identify that the input came from the barcode scanner we want to remove the existing text for it to be overwritten.  If it came from the soft keyboard, we want to leave the text since the user is still typing it in.

Right now we are getting the length of time between characters to decide whether it is from the keyboard or the barcode scanner, but I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to identify the input source from the android.

Maybe a lot of this is going to depend on hardware specifics but hopefully I could get a couple good leads on where to go from here, thanks!

Comment: That is hardware, Android device and OS specific if the barcode scanner is acting an keyboard accessory. (Higher end) scanners usually have an SDK available to directly read from the scanner vs. allowing it to send keystrokes and thus you have more control of the scanning process... You can look at the `source` of the `KeyEvent` to ***try*** to determine if it was from a soft keyboard or a hardware keyboard

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer: I work for Zebra Technologies that produces Android devices with integrated barcode scanners.*

Your approach (measuring delays between characters) should works, but is probably very dependent on the device you're targeting and you can expect different timings moving to a different device.

Usually these Android devices includes a SDK that you can use to read barcodes. In most of the cases these SDKs are only for Java and you should then build your own binding to use them from Xamarin (as a note, Zebra Technologies supports both [Java](http://techdocs.zebra.com/emdk-for-android/6-7/guide/about/) and [Xamarin](http://techdocs.zebra.com/emdk-for-xamarin/2-6/guide/about/)).

A better approach, if you don't need complete control of the barcode scanner (as it seems from your initial approach), is to work with the "Wedge" applications that can inject the barcode data as keycode events that is usually provided on these kind of devices.

**NOTE 1:** Some of these "Wedge" applications allows to insert a pre-fix and a post-fix to the barcode data, that you can configure. You can then use these data to recognize start and end of the barcode data. As an example, on Zebra's Android devices we've `DataWedge` that allows these kind of [Basic Data Formatting](http://techdocs.zebra.com/datawedge/6-6/guide/process/bdf/).

**NOTE 2:** An even better approach (if your device's "Wedge" application support it) is to send the data to the application using Intents. Again, Zebra's DataWedge allows to have different profiles assigned to the foreground activity and [deliver the data as an Intent](http://techdocs.zebra.com/datawedge/6-6/guide/output/intent/).

As you can see, these are solution tight to a single vendor, but working on the timing is probably not much better from this point of view and much more error prone. An alternative, to support multiple HW brand, is that you build your custom "Wedge" application for your particular device. At last [Zebra's Developer Event in Prague - AppForum](https://developer.zebra.com/community/developer-events/appforum-2017/europe) we presented some example on how to do this. You can find some information on this blog post of one of my colleagues: [Writing Enterprise Android applications that capture barcode data and run on multiple devices](http://www.darryncampbell.co.uk/2016/08/16/writing-enterprise-android-applications-that-capture-barcode-data-and-run-on-multiple-devices/).